# sin acceso a imagen en windows forms C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, .net

Tengo una aplicación `Windows Forms` donde envío un email con imágenes, una de esas imágenes es un background donde lo uso como fondo con la propiedad background image , tengo una carpeta dentro de mi proyecto llamada img donde colo las imágenes que uso, pero cuando coloco la **ruta relativa** de la imagen a usar no me muestra nada

[image: 1]

```html
string filePath = "\\img\\back.jpg";

<body style = '' style=\"background-image:url('"+ filePath+ "');\" >
```

Cuando coloco una **ruta absoluta** como por ejemplo una imagen que encuentro en el buscador si la muestra, no se por que no me la muestra

Comment: has probado a poner un . delante de las barras?
string filePath = ".\\img\\back.jpg";

Comment: has mirado tema de permisos?

Comment: @DaniCano si, ya probe colocar punto y doble punto pero no funciona, creo que las imagenes deben estar en alfun servidor de imagenes en internet para colocar la ruta

Comment: La imagen tiene que estar en un servidor publico, o tienes que adjuntar la imagen como string base64.

Comment: @FranciscoHernandez y como la adjunto como string base64?

Comment: Te comparto un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407712, espero te sirva